FIDO 2 passkey implementation
So I am working on a Identity provider and looking to implement login with Passkey which based on online help available I am able to implement and connect devices accordingly. Problem is  a user in our implementation can have different devices to support passkey but FIDO2 implementation cannot derive the device name or type if the registration is done via desktop for these devices. Once registered I can only get unknown device for each registered device making it hard to differentiate. Can smone point me to right direction as to what I am doing wrong ?

ok so I am being  voted down but atleast comment that why are you voting this down ?

Not sure why you are voted down, upvoted, this is a good question. According to my knowledge, devices tend to hide their guids so indeed, you can't easily differentiate them automatically. A common practice is to have a base description built from the user agent header (if present) but users should be able to edit descriptions freely.

Not sure why you're getting downvoted either, but could do with some clarity on the question. .How are you doing the credential request? Browser or did you write your own? Also bit unsure if part you are referring to as problematic is getting information on the device during attestation as well or just on the registration?

For passkeys, the device is not relevant information, it's all about the passkey provider/authenticator (e.g. Google Password Manager, Bitwarden, Yubikey 5 NFC, etc).
Use the AAGUID provided in the passkey creation response to lookup up the name and icons in the passkey provider list here: https://github.com/passkeydeveloper/passkey-authenticator-aaguids
Be sure to look at the README.

In most cases the aaguid comes empty though.

All major passkey providers are sending AAGUIDs today.

Interesting. That probably changed just a while ago. Last time when I checked that, Android phones were the only to send it. Both Windows 10/11 and Apple phones sent nothing.

Windows has been sending it since 2019.
